# Variable available to class methods (within Concerns)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, instance-variables, class-method

I created a Rails Concern for my ActiveModel called `List`

When I run `Product.all` from the Rails Console, I get:

> NameError: undefined local variable or method `parameters' for
>   Product:Class

When parameters is changed to @parameters I get this error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass

## Possible Solutions

Which is better, using a constant  PARAMETERS  or @@Parameters?  Pros and Cons?

## Code

```
module List
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  require 'csv'

    parameters =  [ 
                  :visible,
                  :desc,
                  :value,
                  ]

    attr_accessor(*parameters)

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end

  module ClassMethods 
    def all   
      list = []
      filename = File.join(Rails.root,"app/models/data/#{self.name.downcase}.csv")
      CSV.foreach(filename, headers: true) do |row|
        list << self.new(row.select{|key,_| parameters.include? key.to_sym })
      end
      return list
    end

    def visible
      list = []
      filename = File.join(Rails.root,"app/models/data/#{self.name.downcase}.csv")
      CSV.foreach(filename, headers: true) do |row|
          list << self.new(row.select{|key,_| parameters.include? key.to_sym })  if row['visible']=='1'
      end
      return list
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Why are you overriding the built-in `all` method? In Rails, `all` is meant to return all the rows in the Product table from the database.

Comment: I am using activemodel, not activerecord, so no table.  I'm just emulating the table with my `all` method.  This code is just temporary so I can test of few items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a quick solution, to make `Product.all` and `Product.visible` work with the least amount of modification to your existing code, you can define a `parameters` method inside `module ClassMethods`. For example:

```
def parameters
  @parameters ||= [:visible, :desc, :value]
end
```

This method solution can also serve as a long-term solution if you plan to use the parameters outside of the concern, or if a subclass might want to define its own parameters.

However, if the parameters are only meant to be used inside this concern, and this data will never change, at least not through any application logic, then a constant would be the best solution because it conveys the proper meaning to the reader. I would also freeze it to prevent modification:

```
PARAMETERS = [:visible, :desc, :value].freeze
```

Another option, as Rich mentioned, is to define a class variable. Note that the constant will work whether you define it inside the `List` module, or inside the `ClassMethods` module. However, a class variable will only work inside the `ClassMethods` module if you want `Product` to be able to call it as `parameters`.

Also, note that `self` is implied in any method within `ClassMethods`, so you don't need to specify it. If you defined a `parameters` method, it would be considered a `Product` class method, and if you used `parameters` within the `all` method, it would refer to the class method, not an instance method as suggested by Rich.

Class variables are generally discouraged in Ruby because their side effects are often misunderstood. The Ruby Style Guide recommends avoiding them: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-class-vars

As for speed, I compared the method and constant solutions, and it looks like the constant is faster:

```
require "benchmark/ips"

PARAMETERS = [:visible, :desc, :value].freeze

def parameters
  @parameters ||= [:visible, :desc, :value]
end

def uses_constant
  puts PARAMETERS
end

def uses_method
  puts parameters
end

Benchmark.ips do |x|
  x.report("constant") { uses_constant }
  x.report("method") { uses_method }
  x.compare!
end
```

The result:

```
Comparison:
  constant:  45256.8 i/s
  method:    44799.6 i/s - 1.01x slower
```

Answer (score 1):

Set it as a class var:

```
module List
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    @@parameters =  [:visible, :desc, :value]
    cattr_Accessor :parameters #-> List.parameters && List.new.parameters
```

---

The problem you have right now is you're calling an *instance* method from a *class* method:

```
module ClassMethods 
    self.new(row.select{|key,_| parameters.include? key.to_sym })
```

With the class variable code, you'd be able to run:

```
self.new(row.select{|key,_| self.parameters.include? key.to_sym })
```

Comment: Pros and Cons of using this vs a CONSTANT, like below?

Comment: CONST cannot be changed; class vars can.

Comment: I realize that and in this case, it will never change, but I was wondering more with memory usage, etc.  As CONST seem to not have the same issues with referencing.

Comment: Hmm interesting question. I don't know about mem usage etc; I've only looked at the respective functionality

Comment: I generally avoid class variables, but I updated my answer with benchmark results for constant versus method solutions.

Comment: This was interesting. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A method created with `def` doesn't see local variables present when the method was defined, so your first attempt doesn't work.

With the instance variable, the object your are setting the variable on (your module) and the object trying to read it (the class that included your module) are different. Instance variables don't take part in inheritance at all, so that doesn't work.

What would work is a constant in your List module, ie

```
PARAMETERS = [:visible, :desc, :value]
```

Because your class methods module is inside the List module, code inside it will find constants set on List. Constant lookup first looks at lexical scope (see Module.nesting for this search path) and then inheritance.

Comment: Pros and Cons of using Constant vs @@Parameter, like above?